# how to get session in webview created by httpurlconnection?

Tags: java, android, cookies, webview, httpurlconnection

I am sending request to server using HTTPURLConnection if request is successfull i set the parameter in session which i send along the request.But when i try to get session on jsp page  i don't get the session there.I am loading jsp page on the webview. May i know how can i get the session & i don't want to use the cookies for creating & getting the session?

I am using following code to create the session

```
session.setAttribute("uname",username);
```

Thanks in advance.